# How to know what library must be installed for perl or pm file running?

Tags: perl

I have some perl file and perl module I need it to be running.

Can any one help me find out what library (like pcap or Netpacket) needs to be installed? I am wondering any central location for verification.

I installed almost all the library but does not get the expected output. And when I run

```
$ perl Makefile.PL

Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lwiretap
Writing Makefile for Wtap.
```

Comment: Please post the output you get when running the script.  You likely see something like "Can't locate Some/Module/Name".

Comment: @CraigTreptow How about now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you right there what library you're missing: `wiretap`. Googling appears to indicate it's part of [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), although Wtap's documentation should make that obvious. I suspect installing Wireshark will install the library you're missing.

Comment: Yes it is part of wireshark. I have installed libpcap, libpcap-dev, Netpacket; & there is no as such documentation for this pm:( But Makefile.PL has line like- LIBS => ['-L/usr/lib/wireshark -lwiretap', '-lglib-2.0'], # e.g., '-lm

Comment: None of those is what I said you probably need to install. Did you install Wireshark? Did you install the whole thing (including header files) or just parts of it? (Distros tend to split the headers and the libraries into two packages.) In which directory did you install Wireshark?

Comment: Any way you want. If you need help installing Wireshark, find the proper StackExchange site and indicate what specific problems you are facing.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. It worked with...$ sudo apt-get install wireshark

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what MyWiretap.pm or Wtap are.  They appear to be "home grown" and not available on CPAN or elsewhere.

My assumption is that you might be interested in using [Net::Sharktools](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSharktools) for your purposes.

Comment: I think you are right. MyWiretap.pm is local one & I am trying to execute makefile for the same. My Makefile.PL has line like- LIBS              => ['-L/usr/lib/wireshark -lwiretap', '-lglib-2.0'], # e.g., '-lm'